# Minecraft dupilicate/glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I make a new world in minecraft pc I break a block it reappears and doesn't drop anything till I wait a few minutes.  Is there a solution to this?

Comment: sounds like you are dealing with some lag

Comment: To help us troubleshoot the source of your lag, could you provide a screenshot of your F3 screen, your launcher logs (a setting before you start the game), and the overall specs of your computer?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the [ghost blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Ghost_blocks), a common Minecraft glitch.

> ## What They Are

> Ghost blocks are blocks that are not supposed to be in a certain position, but they are. They occur when the client sees a block in a certain position, but the game does not. The ghost block that results can have interesting properties.

> ## How To Get Rid of Them

> There are a few ways to get rid of ghost blocks. The first involves right-clicking on the ghost block. If the player is holding a block, then the ghost block will be replaced by the block the player is holding.

> The second solution, which is much simpler, is to reload the chunks. This can be done with F3+A, moving, or logging out and logging back in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a solution to that problem.

(Theoratically, not really sure about your specs) It's main cause is that you don't have enough RAM to run the game, how much RAM do you have? try reducing your render distance, since render distance is way too resource heavy for old computers/laptops, How much fps do you have? (smooth? or rough?), try downloading Optifine, do you have Vsync ON to low-hertz monitor? try disabling it, since Vsync limits the fps of the game and synchronizes it to your monitor for more smooth feel, unfortunately, this is the farthest i can help, i don't know your specs yet, please be more specific